# Django: translate parametric messages

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext

I'm using Django 1.11 and I am currently translating my app into other languages. Django is, of course, well-equipped for translations, but I have ran into following problem:

At one point my app generates parametric messages, such as

> *John* has created *Foo*
>
> *Bar* has been changed to *Foo*
>
> *Foo* occurred at *12.00*

and so on. The words in italic are dynamically generated when the message is generated.

Now the problem is this: After the message is generated, I need to store it into the database. **However, at this time I do not know in which language it should be displayed.** That means I cannot translate it at the time of storing.

If the message was non-parametric, I would store it in English and then use `gettext` when displaying the message. I believe this is not possible with the parameters. Also, there are many types of messages and also new ones are constantly being added, therefore I cannot just extend the message model to `|message|param1|param2|` where `message` would be in the form of e.g. `{param1} has created {param2}`. If I did this, the model would be very large and constantly getting larger.

I hope I made the issue clear. Is there any best practise how to do this? Thank you!